# Changing Parallelism in ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, parallel-processing, concurrent-programming

In Java7 ForkJoin pool we can set the parallelism for the pool at the creation time. I could not find any api to change this in the runtime dynamically. Is there a way around to change the parallelism of a ForkJoin pool dynamically?

regards,
Charith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. Although the pool does increase the number of worker threads itself when using join() or managedBlocker(). For more information you can see [this](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html#faulty) article I wrote two years ago.